# How to generate customized JSON response with Spring Boot REST?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I am developing Restful web services with Spring boot. And the CRUD operations are working fine with it. But suddenly new requirement has come that the response needs to be in specific JSON format.

I am getting this response -

```
    "user": {
              "id": 123,
              "name": "shazow"
          }
```

But, the requirement is something like this -

```
    {
       "Timestamp": "2007-10-27T00:51:57Z"
       "status": "ok",
       "code": 200,
       "messages": [],
       "result": {
           "user": {
              "id": 123,
              "name": "shazow"
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, if we retrieve all users then it should be -

```
    {
       "Timestamp": "2007-10-27T00:51:57Z",
       "status": "ok",
       "code": 200,
       "messages": [],
       "users"[
           "user": {
                 "id": 123,
                 "name": "Shazow"
               },

           "user": {
                 "id": 101,
                 "name": "James"
               },

           "user": {
                "id": 152,
                "name": "Mathew"
               }
          ]     
     }
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: CRUD is working, so you already map java objects to json? Do you have something like an [ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) in place?
If so, why don't you just create an object structure of your json an map that?

Comment: Yeap, I have mapped Json with bean with the help of Jackson. But don't know how to map these extra details with it. I'm still a beginner to spring rest.

Comment: Do you need those fields to appear in specific order in your output json?

Comment: yeah, that's right

Comment: **Hint**: Your JSON is invalid. `"users" ` is an array, not an object and the `name` of object `members` should be unique, read  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4

Comment: Ohh Okay, do you have any complete example, so that I can the complete picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a method like I name it response handler in any class and then set your response in it as you like. Please see the code below:

```
   public class ResponseHandler {

    public static ResponseEntity<Object> generateResponse(HttpStatus status, boolean error,String message, Object responseObj) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            map.put("timestamp", new Date());
            map.put("status", status.value());
            map.put("isSuccess", error);
            map.put("message", message);
            map.put("data", responseObj);

            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,status);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            map.clear();
            map.put("timestamp", new Date());
            map.put("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            map.put("isSuccess",false);
            map.put("message", e.getMessage());
            map.put("data", null);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,status);
        }
    }
}
```

Example to use :

```
 @RestController
public class UtilityController {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UtilityController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    ResponseEntity<Object> getAllCountry() {
        LOGGER.info("Country list fetched");
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.OK, false, "Success", null);
    }

}
```

If you have any other queries, please do let me know.

Comment: Do we need to Annotate this class? @pawan

Comment: No. Its a simple class with static method. Just use `classname.methodname` I have added an example.

Comment: What is messgeService here? Is it a class?

Comment: To add message about that response. Now you can use like that.

Comment: If this helps or solve your queries, please consider to accept and upvote the answer so that others can find it useful.

Comment: Actually I have upvoted your answer but I can't cast my vote as my reputation in below 15.

Comment: Hey, I am having trouble applying this method in the controller class.  @pawan

Comment: how do I use this generateResponse method in order to get a response from the controller?

Comment: Can you please show me a complete implementation of it? It will help me lot

Comment: You can check the answer now. I have added the complete code there.

Comment: Glad to know, I could helped. if it helped, please accept the answer so that others can find it useful. Cheers.

Comment: how can I do that, I'm new to this?

Comment: just click on check box

Comment: Hey, in response I'm getting users first and all other info such as timestamp, status, and code at the bottom. Can we get response exactly like above?

Comment: If you want to maintain order of objects, you can use `LinkedHashMap` for that in response handler. However, order doesn't matter, you have to access the data from object itself.